# VS2010 Highlighting Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I've a dark theme in VS2010 I like. When debugging and going back to where I stepped into a method I can hardly read the code.

Does anyone know which font/colour setting it is I need to change to make it more readable?

[image]

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors* then find the *Current Statement* display item.

Answer (score 0):

Go To `Tools-> Options-> Environment-> Fonts and Colors -> DisplayItems -> Current Statement` and change the Itembackground Color....

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Current Statement, this can be changed as follows

Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors -> Current Statement.

If you are referring to the breakpoint line, then this is set with the Breakpoint (Enabled) option under the color settings.